# Copy data between databases using Entity Framework, LINQ and MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq, entity-framework

There is a problem. I have old database with some data, and by another side I have new database with new structure.

Now I need best way (ideas) how to copy data from one table to the another. Problem is some tables have max 1000 records some 32 000 some 640 000, and time to copy 5000+ is really long.

Any best practices ? Sample code below ...

```
public ActionResult ImportTable1()
{
   var oldTable1 = context.OLDTABLE.ToList();

   foreach (var item in oldTable1)
   {
      try
      {
          var cTable = contextNew.NEWTABLE.Where(p => p.fiel1 == item.field1).FirstOrDefault();

          if (cTable == null)
          {
             NEWTABLE nTable = new NEWTABLE
             {
                                field1 = item.field1,
                                field2 = item.field2
             };

             contextNew.NEWTABLE.Add(nTable);
          }
          else
          {
             cTable.field1 = item.field1
             cTable.field2 = item.field2;

             contextNew.Entry(cTable).State = EntityState.Modified;
          }

          IcontextNew.SaveChanges();
      }
      catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
      {
         foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
         {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
               _progresLog = ("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: {1}" + validationError.ErrorMessage);
            }
         }
     }

   return PartialView();
}
```

---

... so bulk now

```
    public void ExperimentalPartsBulk()
    {
        string msisDatabase = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["old"].ToString();
        string newDatabase = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["new"].ToString();

        SqlConnection sourceconnection = new SqlConnection(msisDatabase);
        SqlConnection sourcedestination = new SqlConnection(newDatabase);


        sourceconnection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from ELEMENTS");
        cmd.Connection = sourceconnection;
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Connect to Destination DataBase
        SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(newDatabase);
        destinationConnection.Open();


        SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection);
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ELEMENTSNEW";
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Clear();
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("fielString1", "newString1");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("fielString2", "newStrin2");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("fielFloat1", "newINT1");
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
        reader.Close();

        sourceconnection.Close();
        sourcedestination.Close();

    }
```

problem now is w differences betwen two tables

**fielString1** can be null, **newString1** cant be | 
**fielFloat1** is float now is nullable but  **newINT1** not

How to import with some conditions or to the different types of field ?

Comment: Leave ORM, use [BulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

Comment: I don't think `Entity Framework` is the way to go if you're dealing with batch operations.

Comment: I know but this must be some little program with Entity Framework.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy is what you need here

Comment: Any exception being thrown when using the `SqlBulkCopy`?

Comment: I know the problem now. When i take data from old database i need shape old data, EXAMPLE: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT KOD, NAZWA_ELEMENTU, WAGA_KG FROM PL_ELEMENTY WHERE (KOD IS NOT NULL) AND (WAGA_KG IS NOT NULL)");

Answer (score 0):

Siwek,

Any loop as shown in the first code sample will failed due to performance issues.... as you pointed!

The right approach here is SQL approach. The idea is to "flush" all data to new DB. Flush mean that ALL records (5,000 or 500,000) are stored to new DB with one action! And avoid any loops during extracting, filtering, editing and saving of data, because 640,000 loops takes long time....

Bulk copy is one possible. Issue with bulk copy is that it's hard for you to filter and edit data in this object.

Use ADO.net DataSet to get data from old DB, filter it, edit it, and save it on memory and *flush* it to new DB. DataSet take one step per action (extracting, filtering, editing, etc. ! no loops).

Or, try SQL replication. Replication is the SQL mechanism to copy data from DB "A" table "oneTable" to another DB, "B" with a table "AnotherTable" with a different schema and rules. Try it. I can specify more if you think it's a reasonable solution for you. No code needed, it's can be created using wizard on SQL Management studio, and run whenever needed (via SQL Job agent).

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously consider SSIS or bcp. Otherwise you are looking at a scenario whet you're pulling data from the source server all the way down to the client box where the .net code is executing, then pushing all off that data up to the destination server. Think of the bandwidth being consumed. If you can instead do an SSIS export into the destination, at least it would be eliminating an extra layer of concern.

If you absolutely must pull data down to the client, consider writing the data into bcp formatted files, and then bulkcopying them into the destination server.

I'm pretty sure that you'll find that both of these paths are significantly faster than using plain old ADO.NET sort of approaches.